# all possible x-part combinations of variable amount of items

Tags: java

If I got an array like this:

`String[] items = { "Cat", "Frog", "Dog", "Ferret"};`

For example, all 3-item combinations in this case would be (if I didn't miss any):

```
String[][] combinations = { 
{ "Cat", "Frog", "Dog" }, 
{ "Cat", "Dog", "Ferret" },
{ "Cat", "Frog", "Ferret" }, 
{ "Frog", "Dog", "Ferret" } };
```

How can I get all possible x-item combinations of a variable amount of items using a java method?

Comment: Check this post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/127704/algorithm-to-return-all-combinations-of-k-elements-from-n

Comment: @LorenzoR Thanks, I will have a look into this.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [combinatoricslib](https://code.google.com/p/combinatoricslib/)

There is also a function in [apache commons math](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/util/CombinatoricsUtils.html#combinationsIterator%28int,%20int%29) development version which generates integer combinations: `CombinatoricsUtils.combinationsIterator (3.3)`

You could use that function to generate indexes for you String array and then use those indexes to populate data with actual value.

> ```
> public static Iterator<int[]> combinationsIterator(int n, int k)
> ```
>
> Returns an iterator whose range is the k-element subsets of {0, ..., n
>   - 1} represented as int[] arrays. The arrays returned by the iterator are sorted in descending order and they are visited in lexicographic
>   order with significance from right to left. For example,
>   combinationsIterator(4, 2) returns an Iterator that will generate the
>   following sequence of arrays on successive calls to next(): [0, 1],
>   [0, 2], [1, 2], [0, 3], [1, 3], [2, 3]

**EDIT:**

As OP mentioned, this is a development version at the moment so to download you would have to checkout their source from here: [source](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/source-repository.html) and then build it yourself (with maven)

Comment: Hmm, this does seem to only exist in the development-version 3.3. I could only find version 3.2 for download on http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/download_math.cgi. Maybe there is another page where I can download the development jar or better a method which works the same way in 3.2?

Comment: I updated my answer to add another lib you could use and also the source location of the apache-math which you could use to checkout the source and build it yourself with 'mvn package'

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this:

```
static void combinations2(String[] arr, int len, int startPosition, String[] result, ArrayList<String[]> allResults){
    if (len == 0){
        String[] copy = new String[result.length];
        System.arraycopy(result,0,copy,0,result.length);
        allResults.add(copy);
        return;
    }
    for (int i = startPosition; i <= arr.length-len; i++){
        result[result.length - len] = arr[i];
        combinations2(arr, len-1, i+1, result, allResults);
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
ArrayList<String[]> allResults = new ArrayList<String[]>();
String[] items = { "Cat", "Frog", "Dog", "Ferret"};
combinations2(items, 3, 0, new String[3], allResults);
```